LayoutParams Issue Java
I have this for animating a RIGHT swipe and it works great:
good swipe
if(direction == RIGHT){
    if(distance < 217) {

        layoutParams.leftMargin = (int) distance + startLeftMargin;
        layoutParams.topMargin = startTopMargin;
        call.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        straddle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fold.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = call.getLayoutParams();

        layoutParams.width = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * ((int) distance);

            call.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


    }

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/call"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/call"
    android:gravity="center|start"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_gap"
    android:text="Call"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    />

I have this for animating a LEFT swipe, but it is not working well. As the button moves to the left, the black animation with the word Str. goes to the right. I'd like the black background to stay stationary while the button moves.
bad swipe
} else if(direction == LEFT){
    if(distance < 217) {
        layoutParams.leftMargin = (int) (-distance) + startLeftMargin;
        layoutParams.topMargin = startTopMargin;
        call.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        straddle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fold.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = straddle.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * (int) distance;

        straddle.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    }

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/straddle"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/straddle"
    android:gravity="center|end"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/default_gap"
    android:text="Str."
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

I really can't figure out what the issue might be, if anyone has any ideas i'd really apreciate it.

Did you find the solution for this or you're still looking for one.

I still haven't figured it out
